# Screenshot on Ubuntu terminal Version

Tags: ubuntu, screenshot

Do you know if theres a way to take screenshot in the terminal (Server) Version of Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS?

scrot and "paste" don't work for me, cause there's actually no "screen".

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm using it directly and wanna make a screenshot from htop.
Connecting via ip.

Comment: ah. would any of these work for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/726333/how-to-save-htop-output-to-file :)

Comment: @Rinzwind That suits perfectly what I need! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: A "screenshot" of a text terminal would be equivalent to copying the text in the terminal, right?